# Laravel MIX, how to use single function in multiple files

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, laravel-mix

I have three files:

- my_function.js
- scripts_1.js
- scripts_2.js

my_function.js

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log('my function');
}
```

How can I use this function in both of my files `scripts_1.js` and `scripts_2.js`? I use these two in `users.js` as:

```
require('scripts_1');
require('scripts_2');
```

and in `admins.js` I use only one:

```
require('scripts_2');
```

Later in my `webpack.mix.js` I compile the `users` and `admin` files to two separate minified js files.

If I just use the `require('my_function')` in my `scripts_1` and `scripts_2` files this doesn't work (probably the `myFunction()` is not in the same scope).

However I can make this work if I attach my function to the `window` variable so that the `my_function` looks like this now:

```
window.myFunction = function() { ... }
```

At this point I don't even have to require it in any of the `scripts_1` and `scripts_2` files (but I do in my `users.js` and `admin.js` files) but this feels wrong somehow.

tldr;

I'd like to know how to define a helper js function that I can reuse in multiple other js files by using Laravel MIX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you exporting `myFunction`?

In node, you can do

```
module.exports = {
   myFunction: function () {
     console.log('my function');
   }
}
```

With webpack and friends, you can simply

```
export function myFunction() {
  console.log('my function');
}
```

Then you can import and use the function

```
const someName = require('my_function.js')

someName.myFunction()
```

Exporting the function you are telling that the module (the file in that case), has that function. And when you import the module you will be able to use that funcion, it's some type of public/private behavior, exported functions/objects,... are public to other modules, non exported functions/objects/... are private.

To use a exported function, first you need to import the module in every file you want to use it (require('themodule')). Instead, using `window`, you are attaching in the global object `window` a new property, so once you have imported in some file the module you can use `window.myFunction` in any file. The last is not desirable.

[Here](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-modules) you have the differents types of modules that javascript has.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit noob when it comes to js. I'll test it later today and accept when done. Can you point me to some starter tutorial that explains proper managing of js files? Also, what is the end difference between exporting the function (this is just creating a new global variable like `window`, right?) and saving it to `window`?

Comment: Sure, I've edited the answer to add some explanation and a link which explains three different types of javascript modules.